# Date Timezone Fromat. PHP Vs JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this function to adjust the timezones in created_at, updated_at ... I would like to do the same thing with PHP code in the Laravel format (Version 5.8) how do I do it? Thanks. This JS function is working successfully.

```
const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');           
const formatOrderCreatedAt = new Date(`${order.data.created_at}Z`) || null;         
const formatOrderUpdatedAt = new Date(`${order.data.updated_at}Z`) || null;        
const formatOrderDeletedAt = new Date(`${order.data.deleted_at}Z`) || null;
```

This will return 'dd / mm / yyyy, H / i / s' at the right time according to the person's timezone, who is seeing the date.

Comment: Do you have the user's locale stored anywhere? If not, you would have to send it from the client to your backend, which kind of defeats the purpose, since you already have a mechanism to do this on the client.

Comment: It might be helpful to [serialize](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization) the dates in laravel with `Carbon::toIsoString()` or `Carbon::toIso8601ZuluString()` so you only need your first line in JavaScript.